# Añadir un nuevo elemento a una combobox

Tags: python, lista, tkinter, combobox

Estoy añadiendo elementos a mi proyecto y estoy con una Combobox, me gustaría poder añadirle manualmente elementos nuevos con un botón a la Combobox, pero está claro que algo no estoy haciendo bien.

Os dejo el código, que he resumido solo con el error que no se solucionar.

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox #libreria IMPRESCINDIBLE para meter ventanas emergentes
from tkinter import filedialog #libreria que necesito para estas ventanas
from tkinter import ttk #libreria que necesito para estas ventanas

raiz=Tk()

def actualiza_valores(num):
    values=list(proyecto["values"])
    proyecto["values"]=values+[num]

ancho_ventana = 500 #ancho de la ventana
alto_ventana = 200 #alto de la ventana

x_ventana = raiz.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - ancho_ventana // 2 #posición del ancho de la ventana
y_ventana = raiz.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - alto_ventana // 2 #posición del alto de la ventana

posicion = str(ancho_ventana) + "x" + str(alto_ventana) + "+" + str(x_ventana) + "+" + str(y_ventana) #determinación de la posición de la pantalla

raiz.geometry(posicion)

proyecto=ttk.Combobox(raiz,state="readonly")
proyecto['values']=('1','2','3','4') #valores que entran en la combobox
proyecto.place(x=200,y=25)
pregunta=Label(raiz, text="Inserta un nuevo proyecto")
pregunta.place(x=50,y=75)
cuadro=Entry(raiz)
cuadro.place(x=215,y=75)
boton=Button(raiz,text="Actualizar",command=actualiza_valores(cuadro.get()))
boton.place(x=220,y=120)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

El problema está en esta linea:

```
boton=Button(raiz,text="Actualizar",command=actualiza_valores(cuadro.get()))
```

Cuando colocas paréntesis a la derecha de una función, esta se ejecuta inmediatamente. Como el entry está vacío, añade un item vacío al combobox.

Como esta función termina por devolver None, el valor que recibe command es None. Por lo que termina siendo equivalente a `command=None`. Cuando a command se le pasa None, no se relaciona ninguna función al botón. Por eso el botón no funciona.

Otra cosa. Si quieres obtener el valor actual del entry, tienes que hacer `cuadro.get()` siempre que se presione el botón.

#### Solución

Evita poner paréntesis a la derecha de tu función. Para lograr esto, puedes directamente enlazar la función sin llamarla. Dentro de la función, obtenemos el valor actual que contiene el entry.

Así quedaría tu función

```
# El botón no le pasa ningún argumento a la función actualiza valores.
# Por lo que no debe aceptar argumentos.
def actualiza_valores():
    num = cuadro.get()

    values=list(proyecto["values"])
    proyecto["values"]=values+[num]
```

Y así quedaría la linea donde se crea el botón:

```
boton=Button(raiz,text="Actualizar",command=actualiza_valores)
```

Por otro lado, si necesitas pasar argumentos a actualiza_valores siempre que se presione el botón, puedes usar [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Al provenir de la librería estandar, no es necesario instalar nada.

Agrega esta linea entre tus importaciones:

```
from functools import partial
```

Tu función quedaría así:

```
def actualiza_valores(num):
    values=list(proyecto["values"])
    proyecto["values"]=values+[num.get()]
```

Y la linea donde se crea el botón así:

```
boton=Button(raiz,text="Actualizar",command=partial(actualiza_valores, cuadro))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha ayudado mucho a corregirlo.

Comment: De nada compañero c: